# C++ Valgrind: Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)

Tags: c++, matrix, valgrind

So I'm implementing a weighted digraph with templates using a dynamic matrix (which I also implemented).

The thing is, when I use my Matrix class on its own it works fine, but inside the Graph class it just doesn't and I don't understand why. I was hoping someone could help me out.

Here is the `Matrix` class. I tested it directly on `main.cpp` with Valgrind and it didn't show anything.

```
template <typename Type>
class Matrix {

private:
    Type** matrix;
    unsigned size;
    Type null;

public:
    Matrix();
    Matrix(unsigned size, Type null);
    Matrix(const Matrix& matrix);
    ~Matrix();
    Type getData(unsigned row, unsigned col);
    void insert(Type data, unsigned row, unsigned col);
    void freeMatrixResources(Type** matrix);
    void resize(unsigned size);
    void assignNull(unsigned int beginRow, unsigned int endRow, unsigned int beginCol, unsigned int endCol);
    void copyData(Type** matrix, unsigned begin, unsigned end);
    void printMatrix();
    Type operator()(unsigned int row, unsigned int col);
    friend ostream& operator << (ostream& o, const Matrix<Type> &m);
};

template <typename Type>
ostream& operator << (ostream& out, const Matrix<Type> &m) {
    for (int i = 0; i < m.size; ++i) {
        out << "\t\t";
        for (int j = 0; j < m.size; ++j) {
            out << m.getData(i, j) << "\t";
        }
        out << "\n";
    }
    out << "\n";
    return out;
}

template <typename Type>
Type Matrix<Type>:: operator()(unsigned int row, unsigned int col) {
    return matrix[row][col];
}

template <typename Type>
Matrix<Type>:: Matrix() {
    matrix = 0;
    size = 0;
    null = 0;
}

template <typename Type>
Matrix<Type>:: Matrix(unsigned size, Type null) {
    matrix = new Type*[size];
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        matrix[i] = new Type[size];
    this->size = size;
    this->null = null;
    assignNull(0, size, 0, size);
}

template <typename Type>
Matrix<Type>:: Matrix(const Matrix<Type> &matrix) {
    this->matrix = new Type*[matrix.size];
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.size; ++i)
        matrix[i] = new Type[matrix.size];
    copyData(matrix,0,0);
}

template <typename Type>
Matrix<Type>:: ~Matrix() {
    freeMatrixResources(matrix);
}

template <typename Type>
Type Matrix<Type>:: getData(unsigned row, unsigned col) {
    return matrix[row][col];
}

template <typename Type>
void Matrix<Type>:: insert(Type data, unsigned int row, unsigned int col) {
    matrix[row][col] = data;
}

template <typename Type>
void Matrix<Type>:: freeMatrixResources(Type** matrix) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        delete [] matrix[i];
    }
    delete [] matrix;
}

template <typename Type>
void Matrix<Type>:: resize(unsigned int newSize) {
    if (this->size != newSize) {

        Type** aux = matrix;
        matrix = new Type*[newSize];
        for (int i = 0; i < newSize; ++i)
            matrix[i] = new Type[newSize];

        if (this->size < newSize) {
            copyData(aux, 0, this->size);
            assignNull(this->size, newSize, 0, newSize);
            assignNull(0, newSize, this->size, newSize);
        }
        else
            copyData(aux, 0, newSize);

        freeMatrixResources(aux);
        this->size = newSize;
    }
}

template <typename Type>
void Matrix<Type>:: assignNull(unsigned int beginRow, unsigned int endRow, unsigned int beginCol, unsigned int endCol) {
    for (int i = beginRow; i < endRow; ++i) {
        for (int j = beginCol; j < endCol; ++j) {
            matrix[i][j] = null;
        }
    }
}

template <typename Type>
void Matrix<Type>:: copyData(Type** matrix, unsigned int begin, unsigned int end) {
    for (int i = begin; i < end; ++i) {
        for (int j = begin; j < end; ++j) {
            this->matrix[i][j] = matrix[i][j];
        }
    }
}

template <typename Type>
void Matrix<Type>:: printMatrix() {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        cout << "\t\t";
        for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j) {
            cout << matrix[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    cout << "\n";
}
```

But then, when I run the Graph program with `valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full "./cmake-build-debug/graphTemplates"` the output says `Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation, Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)`

```
==155342== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==155342== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==155342== Using Valgrind-3.15.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==155342== Command: ./cmake-build-debug/graphTemplates
==155342== 
==155342== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==155342==    at 0x109BEC: Matrix<int>::resize(unsigned int) (Matrix.h:100)
==155342==    by 0x10974B: Graph<int, int>::addEdge(int, int, int) (Graph.h:119)
==155342==    by 0x109327: main (main.cpp:36)
==155342== 
==155342== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==155342==    at 0x109C0D: Matrix<int>::resize(unsigned int) (Matrix.h:103)
==155342==    by 0x10974B: Graph<int, int>::addEdge(int, int, int) (Graph.h:119)
==155342==    by 0x109327: main (main.cpp:36)
==155342== 
==155342== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==155342==    at 0x483C530: operator new[](unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==155342==    by 0x109C1A: Matrix<int>::resize(unsigned int) (Matrix.h:103)
==155342==    by 0x10974B: Graph<int, int>::addEdge(int, int, int) (Graph.h:119)
==155342==    by 0x109327: main (main.cpp:36)
==155342== 
==155342== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==155342==    at 0x109C39: Matrix<int>::resize(unsigned int) (Matrix.h:104)
==155342==    by 0x10974B: Graph<int, int>::addEdge(int, int, int) (Graph.h:119)
==155342==    by 0x109327: main (main.cpp:36)
==155342== 
==155342== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==155342==    at 0x109C4B: Matrix<int>::resize(unsigned int) (Matrix.h:105)
==155342==    by 0x10974B: Graph<int, int>::addEdge(int, int, int) (Graph.h:119)
==155342==    by 0x109327: main (main.cpp:36)
==155342== 
==155342== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==155342==    at 0x483C530: operator new[](unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==155342==    by 0x109C74: Matrix<int>::resize(unsigned int) (Matrix.h:105)
==155342==    by 0x10974B: Graph<int, int>::addEdge(int, int, int) (Graph.h:119)
==155342==    by 0x109327: main (main.cpp:36)
==155342== 
==155342== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==155342==    at 0x109C88: Matrix<int>::resize(unsigned int) (Matrix.h:107)
==155342==    by 0x10974B: Graph<int, int>::addEdge(int, int, int) (Graph.h:119)
==155342==    by 0x109327: main (main.cpp:36)
==155342== 
==155342== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==155342==    at 0x109D51: Matrix<int>::assignNull(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int) (Matrix.h:122)
==155342==    by 0x109CC8: Matrix<int>::resize(unsigned int) (Matrix.h:109)
==155342==    by 0x10974B: Graph<int, int>::addEdge(int, int, int) (Graph.h:119)
==155342==    by 0x109327: main (main.cpp:36)
==155342== 
==155342== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==155342==    at 0x109D5F: Matrix<int>::assignNull(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int) (Matrix.h:123)
==155342==    by 0x109CC8: Matrix<int>::resize(unsigned int) (Matrix.h:109)
==155342==    by 0x10974B: Graph<int, int>::addEdge(int, int, int) (Graph.h:119)
==155342==    by 0x109327: main (main.cpp:36)
==155342== 
==155342== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==155342==    at 0x109D51: Matrix<int>::assignNull(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int) (Matrix.h:122)
==155342==    by 0x109CE9: Matrix<int>::resize(unsigned int) (Matrix.h:110)
==155342==    by 0x10974B: Graph<int, int>::addEdge(int, int, int) (Graph.h:119)
==155342==    by 0x109327: main (main.cpp:36)
==155342== 
==155342== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==155342==    at 0x109D5F: Matrix<int>::assignNull(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int) (Matrix.h:123)
==155342==    by 0x109CE9: Matrix<int>::resize(unsigned int) (Matrix.h:110)
==155342==    by 0x10974B: Graph<int, int>::addEdge(int, int, int) (Graph.h:119)
==155342==    by 0x109327: main (main.cpp:36)
==155342== 
==155342== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==155342==    at 0x109A5E: Matrix<int>::insert(int, unsigned int, unsigned int) (Matrix.h:87)
==155342==    by 0x109794: Graph<int, int>::addEdge(int, int, int) (Graph.h:121)
==155342==    by 0x109327: main (main.cpp:36)
==155342== 
                Edge connecting 3 and 1 with cost 7 added successfully!
==155342== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==155342==    at 0x109EB3: Matrix<int>::freeMatrixResources(int**) (Matrix.h:92)
==155342==    by 0x109A99: Matrix<int>::~Matrix() (Matrix.h:77)
==155342==    by 0x10958E: Graph<int, int>::~Graph() (Graph.h:84)
==155342==    by 0x10934B: main (main.cpp:30)
==155342== 
==155342== 
==155342== HEAP SUMMARY:
==155342==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==155342==   total heap usage: 14 allocs, 14 frees, 73,900 bytes allocated
==155342== 
==155342== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==155342== 
==155342== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==155342== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==155342== ERROR SUMMARY: 35 errors from 13 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
valentina@valentina-Lenovo-Yoga-C740-14IML:~/Documentos/Algo II/Plantillvalentina@valentina-Lenovo-Yoga-C740-14IML:~/Documentos/Algo II/Plantillvalentina@valentina-Lenovo-Yoga-C740-14IML:~/Documentos/Algo II/Plantillvalentina@valentina-Lenovo-Yoga-C740-14IML:~/Documentos/Algo II/Plantillas de estructuras/graphTemplates$ v
algrind --tool=memcheck --xml=yes --xml-file=/tmp/valgrind --leak-check=full "./cmake-build-debug/graphTemplates"

        ========================= GRAPH ================================

                Edge connecting 1 and 2 with cost 5 added successfully!


                9999999 5       
                9999999 9999999 

                Edge connecting 1 and 2 with cost 4 added successfully!
                Edge connecting 3 and 1 with cost 7 added successfully!

        ================================================================
valentina@valentina-Lenovo-Yoga-C740-14IML:~/Documentos/Algo II/Plantillas de estructuras/graphTemplates$ valgrind --tool=memcheck --track-origins=yes --leak-check=full "./cmake-build-debug/graphTemplates"==155816== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==155816== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==155816== Using Valgrind-3.15.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==155816== Command: ./cmake-build-debug/graphTemplates
==155816== 


        ========================= GRAPH ================================

                Edge connecting 1 and 2 with cost 5 added successfully!


                9999999 5       
                9999999 9999999 

                Edge connecting 1 and 2 with cost 4 added successfully!
==155816== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==155816==    at 0x109BEC: Matrix<int>::resize(unsigned int) (Matrix.h:100)
==155816==    by 0x10974B: Graph<int, int>::addEdge(int, int, int) (Graph.h:119)
==155816==    by 0x109327: main (main.cpp:36)
==155816==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==155816==    at 0x109289: main (main.cpp:7)
==155816== 
==155816== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==155816==    at 0x109C0D: Matrix<int>::resize(unsigned int) (Matrix.h:103)
==155816==    by 0x10974B: Graph<int, int>::addEdge(int, int, int) (Graph.h:119)
==155816==    by 0x109327: main (main.cpp:36)
==155816==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==155816==    at 0x109289: main (main.cpp:7)
==155816== 
==155816== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==155816==    at 0x483C530: operator new[](unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==155816==    by 0x109C1A: Matrix<int>::resize(unsigned int) (Matrix.h:103)
==155816==    by 0x10974B: Graph<int, int>::addEdge(int, int, int) (Graph.h:119)
==155816==    by 0x109327: main (main.cpp:36)
==155816==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==155816==    at 0x109289: main (main.cpp:7)
==155816== 
==155816== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==155816==    at 0x109C39: Matrix<int>::resize(unsigned int) (Matrix.h:104)
==155816==    by 0x10974B: Graph<int, int>::addEdge(int, int, int) (Graph.h:119)
==155816==    by 0x109327: main (main.cpp:36)
==155816==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==155816==    at 0x109289: main (main.cpp:7)
==155816== 
==155816== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==155816==    at 0x109C4B: Matrix<int>::resize(unsigned int) (Matrix.h:105)
==155816==    by 0x10974B: Graph<int, int>::addEdge(int, int, int) (Graph.h:119)
==155816==    by 0x109327: main (main.cpp:36)
==155816==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==155816==    at 0x109289: main (main.cpp:7)
==155816== 
==155816== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==155816==    at 0x483C530: operator new[](unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==155816==    by 0x109C74: Matrix<int>::resize(unsigned int) (Matrix.h:105)
==155816==    by 0x10974B: Graph<int, int>::addEdge(int, int, int) (Graph.h:119)
==155816==    by 0x109327: main (main.cpp:36)
==155816==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==155816==    at 0x109289: main (main.cpp:7)
==155816== 
==155816== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==155816==    at 0x109C88: Matrix<int>::resize(unsigned int) (Matrix.h:107)
==155816==    by 0x10974B: Graph<int, int>::addEdge(int, int, int) (Graph.h:119)
==155816==    by 0x109327: main (main.cpp:36)
==155816==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==155816==    at 0x109289: main (main.cpp:7)
==155816== 
==155816== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==155816==    at 0x109D51: Matrix<int>::assignNull(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int) (Matrix.h:122)
==155816==    by 0x109CC8: Matrix<int>::resize(unsigned int) (Matrix.h:109)
==155816==    by 0x10974B: Graph<int, int>::addEdge(int, int, int) (Graph.h:119)
==155816==    by 0x109327: main (main.cpp:36)
==155816==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==155816==    at 0x109289: main (main.cpp:7)
==155816== 
==155816== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==155816==    at 0x109D5F: Matrix<int>::assignNull(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int) (Matrix.h:123)
==155816==    by 0x109CC8: Matrix<int>::resize(unsigned int) (Matrix.h:109)
==155816==    by 0x10974B: Graph<int, int>::addEdge(int, int, int) (Graph.h:119)
==155816==    by 0x109327: main (main.cpp:36)
==155816==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==155816==    at 0x109289: main (main.cpp:7)
==155816== 
==155816== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==155816==    at 0x109D51: Matrix<int>::assignNull(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int) (Matrix.h:122)
==155816==    by 0x109CE9: Matrix<int>::resize(unsigned int) (Matrix.h:110)
==155816==    by 0x10974B: Graph<int, int>::addEdge(int, int, int) (Graph.h:119)
==155816==    by 0x109327: main (main.cpp:36)
==155816==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==155816==    at 0x109289: main (main.cpp:7)
==155816== 
==155816== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==155816==    at 0x109D5F: Matrix<int>::assignNull(unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int) (Matrix.h:123)
==155816==    by 0x109CE9: Matrix<int>::resize(unsigned int) (Matrix.h:110)
==155816==    by 0x10974B: Graph<int, int>::addEdge(int, int, int) (Graph.h:119)
==155816==    by 0x109327: main (main.cpp:36)
==155816==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==155816==    at 0x109289: main (main.cpp:7)
==155816== 
==155816== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==155816==    at 0x109A5E: Matrix<int>::insert(int, unsigned int, unsigned int) (Matrix.h:87)
==155816==    by 0x109794: Graph<int, int>::addEdge(int, int, int) (Graph.h:121)
==155816==    by 0x109327: main (main.cpp:36)
==155816==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==155816==    at 0x109289: main (main.cpp:7)
==155816== 
==155816== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==155816==    at 0x109EB3: Matrix<int>::freeMatrixResources(int**) (Matrix.h:92)
==155816==    by 0x109A99: Matrix<int>::~Matrix() (Matrix.h:77)
==155816==    by 0x10958E: Graph<int, int>::~Graph() (Graph.h:84)
==155816==    by 0x10934B: main (main.cpp:30)
==155816==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==155816==    at 0x109289: main (main.cpp:7)
==155816== 
==155816== 
==155816== HEAP SUMMARY:
==155816==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==155816==   total heap usage: 14 allocs, 14 frees, 73,900 bytes allocated
==155816== 
==155816== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==155816== 
==155816== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==155816== ERROR SUMMARY: 35 errors from 13 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Here are the methods in the Graph class which Valgrind complains

```
template<typename Type, typename Cost>
Graph<Type, Cost>:: ~Graph() {
    delete costsMatrix;
    delete vertices;
}

template<typename Type, typename Cost>
void Graph<Type, Cost>:: addEdge(Type begin, Type end, Cost cost) {
    if (existsVertex(begin) && existsVertex(end)) {
        costsMatrix->insert(cost, vertices->getPosition(begin), vertices->getPosition(end));
    }
    else if (existsVertex(begin)) {
        costsMatrix->resize(elements + 1);
        vertices->insertAtEnd(end);
        costsMatrix->insert(cost, vertices->getPosition(begin), elements);
        elements += 1;
    }
    else if(existsVertex(end)) {
        costsMatrix->resize(elements + 1);
        vertices->insertAtEnd(begin);
        costsMatrix->insert(cost, elements, vertices->getPosition(end));
        elements += 1;
    }
    else {
        costsMatrix->resize(elements + 2);
        vertices->insertAtEnd(begin);
        vertices->insertAtEnd(end);
        elements += 2;
        costsMatrix->insert(cost, vertices->getPosition(begin), vertices->getPosition(end));
    }
    cout << "\t\tEdge connecting " << begin << " and " << end << " with cost " << cost << " added successfully!\n";
}
```

I know I could use std library for the matrix, but I was asked not to

**Update:** The problem was that in one of the paths I had, I was not initializing the attribute `elements` correctly. Thanks all for the help

Comment: How does `elements` get its value?

Comment: It's a graph's attribute (type `int`). I have two constructors: when the graph is instantiated with no parameters it's set to 0, if it's instantiated with a new edge it's set to 1 if the edge's vertices are equal or to 2 if they're different. Then I increment/decrement it whenever a new vertex is inserted or an existent one is deleted

Comment: The error seems to be about `newSize`, which comes from `elements`. So there must be a path through the code that doesn't initialize `elements`.

Comment: Please add markers at the relevant lines - line 100 of Matrix.h and line 119 of Graph.h

Comment: @Barmar That was it! At some point, I forgot to initialize `elements`. Could you tell me where did you see that in the output valgrind shows? Because I spent several days looking in the wrong place :/

Answer (score 0):

The error says that there's an uninitialized value being used in a "conditional jump or move", which basically means a conditional statement such as `if`. It says that the error is happening the `Matrix<int>::resize(unsigned int)` method. So it must be referring to

```
if (this->size != newSize)
```

which means that either `this->size` or `newSize` is uninitialized.

Another valgrind error says that an uninitialized value is being used in `operator new[](unsigned long)` being called from the `resize` method. So that must be referring to

```
matrix = new Type*[newSize];
```

So this has narrowed down the problem to the `newSize` variable. This is a function parameter, so we have to step back to where the function is called. The stack trace says it was called from `Graph<int, int>::addEdge(int, int, int)`. All the calls are similar to:

```
costsMatrix->resize(elements + 1);
```

so the problem must be that the `elements` variable is not initialized.